# The answerer of a question must be involved in approving edits to the answer

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, moderation

Now that I have a reputation of over 2000 I am asked to moderate edits.  I have seen a lot of edits of answers that add information.  Adding or modifying the information of an answer should be done in a transparent way, either adding a comment or another answer.  Or it should require the person that answered the question to approve the edit.

I realize this has been discussed in other questions, but I want to provide this example:

[image]

I'm not saying this is a bad edit, but it seems like something that must be made in collaboration with the person that answered the question.

When an edit of an answer doesn't involve the original answerer of the question then fact that it was edited and approved should be made more visible to the rest of the community.

Comment: This would eliminate about 80% of all valid suggested edits, and the remaining 20% would take hours or even days longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editing guidelines already state that edits should not be radically changing the content of the posts, or the author's intentions.  If they do, the edits *should* be rejected.

To help account for those cases that are missed (because yes, they do happen) or for cases where editors and reviewers mistakenly felt that the author's intentions were preserved, the author of the post is notified when it is edited, and all edits are indicated in the revision history of every post.  The author can always roll back an edit that they feel makes an inappropriate change (or just revert certain problematic portions of it).

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is more like a wiki than an editorial; it takes knowledge from everyone to provide the best answer. It's basically somewhere in the middle from a blog/news site and a wiki when editing answers is concerned; others can edit your answers (as in a wiki) while it's your name what appears there (as in a blog).

That being said, there's a practical point. **The answerer might not come back in a week**. The person asking the question might benefit from the edit in the spot. StackOverflow is about providing useful answers, so it seems easy: provide the best answer in the shortest time possible.

Note that the answerer always have the chance to revert the edit and that it's already been peer-reviewed.